# gitweb hide index project_list

Tags: git, gitweb

It's possible disable the index view of gitweb page?
My boss don't want that users can access to the link:

```
local.repo/git/?a=project_list
```

but they can access to specific inner projects:

```
local.repo/git/?p=Group0/project1
local.repo/git/?p=Group0/project2
...
local.repo/git/?p=Group9/project0
...
```

P.s.: the server is a Debian 7

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways: you can hand-craft a projects list (see the gitweb documentation, section "Projects list file format" at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb) or you can blacklist the specific URL using e.g. mod_rewrite.

But none of these solutions will block unauthorized users for real. I would strongly recommend you to install a proper tool like GitLab, which allows you to manage visibility explicitly and also takes care of all the little shenanigans hosting a set of repositories semi-publicly.

I for my part have a GitLab installation and Gitweb, where Gitweb shows all public projects with a script generated project list and a bunch of symlinks.